# heroku run python manage.py collectstatic

Tags: python, django, heroku, static, django-staticfiles

When I run this command I get this error:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic 

Running python manage.py collectstatic on myapp... up, run.1771
You have requested to collect static files at the destination location as specified in your settings:

    /app/static_in_env/static_root

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: 

$ yes

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/my app/static_in_pro/our_static'
```

How can I fix this problem?

my settings for static files

```
# Static asset configuration 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_in_env","static_root")
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_in_pro","our_static"),  
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env","media_root")
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) –
```

Comment: Please show your static file settings.

Comment: this is my settings for staticfiles 
# Static asset configuration

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env","static_root")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro","our_static"),
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env","media_root")

urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: I tried to do it myself, but realized I had to make guesses because of lost of format, so instead: Please edit your question to include your settings.  (Also, including your WSGI; are you using the Heroku Django quickstart suggestion with cling?)

Comment: Check if the directory `'/app/my app/static_in_pro/our_static'` exists in your server, if not than create it .. if you could not create, than change the variable that have the value`app/my app` to an existing directory

Comment: the directory exist but like this app/static_in_pro/our_static 
and i cannot create folders in my repo on heroku from the bash

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/app/my app/static_in_pro/our_static` doesn't exist as mentioned in the error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/my app/static_in_pro/our_static'
```

so create it and any non-existing parent directory than rerun your command.